# adding view elements within a tablerow

Tags: android, tablelayout, android-tablelayout

I have a screen which has a tablelayout defined in the xml with three stretch columns. Now in my code I am  populating the table rows inside the tablelayout based on some backend data fetched at runtime.
Now I want to create an action wherein by clicking any tablerow, some details data is shown by expanding the table row. And by clicking the tabelrow again, the data should get collapsed.
I have tried using the code below, however it is not working and I don't get the tablerow details data displayed/expanded after click. Any help will be much appreciated.

main.xml below

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.bfp.quiztemplate.ScoresActivity" >

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/quizSpinner" >

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/displayScoresTable"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:stretchColumns="0,1,2"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    </TableLayout>

   </ScrollView>
```

my activity class below

```
      TableLayout  tl = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.displayScoresTable);
        for (int i = 0; i<dataArray.length; i++){
             TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);
             tr.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.cell_shape_scores);
             tr.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

                //add more view elelemtns inside tablerow
            TextView myText = new TextView(this);
            myText.setText ("test");
            LayoutParams textViewLayoutParams = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                myText .setLayoutParams(textViewLayoutParams);
                tr.addView(myText );

             //now the code for expand/collpase logic

             tr.setTag(rowCount);
             tr.setId(rowCount);
                 tr.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
                 public void onClick(View v) {
                   rowCount = (Integer) v.getTag();
                   TextView tv1 = new TextView(ScoresActivity.this);
                   TextView tv2=new TextView(ScoresActivity.this);
                   TableRow.LayoutParams trparams = new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                   tv1.setLayoutParams(trparams);
                   tv2.setLayoutParams(trparams);
                   tv1.setText("Hello1!");
                   tv2.setText("Hello2!");
                   TableRow trow = new TableRow(ScoresActivity.this);
                   trow.setLayoutParams(trparams);
                   trow.addView(tv1);
                   trow.addView(tv2);
                   TableRow currentRow = (TableRow)findViewById(rowCount);
                   currentRow .addView(trow);
              }});

      tl.addView(tr, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to finally solve by using addview(tablerow, index) property of tablelayout. For expanding I had to add so many rows at tat position and remove them for collapsing.